# Is it documented anywhere that the array `instantiateWithOwner` returns is ordered in a specific way?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I've lately seen some code sample that used `instantiateWithOwner` to load the cells for a `UITableView` this way:

`cell = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil][0];`

while it's cleaner and more compact than having a property outlet as a prototype cell, I wonder if it's guaranteed(aka documented) that the first top level object in the interface builder will always be the first in the array returned by `instantiateWithOwner`. It may be the case at this point, but if not documented(undefined), it could change in the future, causing trouble for nibs that have more than one top level object and instantiate cells like this.

Comment: Well if you're writing this code then you presumably control the `.xib` so if you are using this style of code never have another top level object.

Comment: Ah, you're right. But my question goes beyond that. You control the nib, and put your object first, however, it may happen that `instantiateWithOwner` will not return an ordered array in a future OS, then your app will probably crash. However, if this is documented, Apple will sure thing stick with it, so it won't break apps that follow their docs after all.

Comment: [`-[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINib_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINib/instantiateWithOwner:options:) returns an `NSArray` which is by definition ordered. Apple couldn't change that without breaking backwards compatibility.

Comment: @KurtRevis Being "unordered" was just an example. It could be *ordered* in a different way.

Comment: "The order in which the nib-loading code calls the awakeFromNib methods of objects is not guaranteed." Check the link in my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find anywhere that documents the order of the array returned by `instantiateWithOwner` specifically, but the documentation *does* talk about [the order that nib-loading code calls awakeFromNib](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html):

> The order in which the nib-loading code calls the `awakeFromNib` methods of objects is not guaranteed.

My assumption is that this means the order of the array returned by `instantiateWithOwner` is also not guaranteed. To *guarantee* order when pulling multiple objects out of a xib, I usually start by configuring each object's tag through interface builder with a unique (ascending) number. Then, your code would look something like this:

```
NSArray *cells = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"tag" ascending:YES]]];
cell = cells[0];
```